# Why does DevC++ compile old code instead of the one that I am trying to compile?

Tags: compilation, dev-c++

I was doing some competitive programming problems on Dev C++ on my machine. I tried compiling and running a program but what it (DevCPP) instead was doing was that it was running previously compiled code. And this isn't the first time it has happened, it has happened to me numerous times before.

Is this something only I am facing (I don't think that's a probable case), or is it something that is common on like DevC++? Why does this happen? Also, and most importantly, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some screenshots maybe? I personally faced this issue when I started out programming cause I didn't CTRL+S each time after making changes and hence the compiler kept giving results for the old code.

Unless this isn't the issue did you try re-installing the software or try it on a different IDE?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well, I can't really share the screenshots because of some issues. As far as saving the file is concerned, I am absolutely certain that I did that, in fact that's the reason I am posting this here.